# Как правильно откатиться к давнему коммиту, восстановив все удалённые файлы?

Tags: git, git-revert

Нужно восстановить структуру проекта из определённого коммита со всеми файлами, которые могли быть удалены по пути к последнему комиту. Одним revert-ом к нужному комиту все файлы не вернулись.

Как правильно вернуть весь проект к нужному комиту?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Команда `revert` - НЕ возвращает, а УДАЛЯЕТ действие заданных коммитов. Чтобы вернуться можно использовать команду `checkout` желательно с добавлением имени новой ветки.

`git revert AAAA..BBBB` - создаёт новый коммит с действием, как будто не было коммитов c `AAAA` по `BBBB`.

`git checkout AAAA -b NAME` - переходит в состояние как было в коммите `AAAA` и создаёт ветку с именем `NAME`.